Find smallest radius so that circles do not intersect the given line of given slope
A lattice point in the plane is a point with integer coordinates. Suppose that circles with
radius r are drawn using all lattice points as centers. Find the smallest value of r such that any line with slope $(2/5)$ intersects some of these circles.
I have seen some solutions of this problem, but could not understand them, so to understand better, I am posting this here. If the line is $y = (2/5)x + c$, then this line will not pass through the lattice points if $c$ is not an integer. Also, if this line intersects the circle with center at $(a,b)$ of radius $r$, then it will also intersect the circle with center at $(a + 5k, b + 2k)$ of radius $r$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. These are the insights I have got so far. How do I proceed further ?

My recommendation would be to change up how you view this problem. "Project" the circles along these 2/5 slope lines onto the y-axis. What does a circle of radius $r$ become? Where do the centers go to? Hence, how wide must the radius be in order to cover the y-axis?
